# how can i removing sinusoidal noise w\ frequency domain in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, dft, noise-reduction

i'm  trying to remove '5 lines' in section, in music papers, my original image is this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_(Mozart)#/media/File:K626_Requiem_Mozart.jpg

First, i apply gaussian filter and binarized with threshold (min:100, max 255).
Then applying dft to this image, erase some appropriate lines, and reconstruct image by inverse dft.

i use sample code in opencv documentation, actually i doubt myself that i understand this code. :(
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html

in this sample code, there's 2 Mats. one is 'complexI' for spectrum, another is 'magI' for actual visualized. the result of cv::dft is complexI, magI is normalized complexI. my question is this. how can i add a black line(to cancel in freq domain) and reconstruct?

Comment: Gabor filter may work. wikipedia links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter

Comment: BTW, is '5 lines' a sinusoidal noise? Just try some other methods like eroding.

Comment: thunderstick, thanks for your reply.
'5 lines' are not perfect sinusoidal noise but it's pattern, can removed by fourier transform. that was my idea.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV (now) provides a detailed tutorial on how to deal with periodic noise by spectral filtering: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/d0b/tutorial_periodic_noise_removing_filter.html

It hinges on using `cv::dft()`, `cv::idft()`, `cv::mulSpectrums()`, and `cv::magnitude()`.

The core function (from the tutorial) to perform the filtering goes like so:

```
void filter2DFreq(const Mat& inputImg, Mat& outputImg, const Mat& H)
{
    Mat planes[2] = { Mat_<float>(inputImg.clone()), Mat::zeros(inputImg.size(), CV_32F) };
    Mat complexI;
    merge(planes, 2, complexI);
    // find FT of image
    dft(complexI, complexI, DFT_SCALE);

    Mat planesH[2] = { Mat_<float>(H.clone()), Mat::zeros(H.size(), CV_32F) };
    Mat complexH;
    merge(planesH, 2, complexH);
    Mat complexIH;

    // apply spectral filter
    mulSpectrums(complexI, complexH, complexIH, 0);

    // reconstruct the filtered image
    idft(complexIH, complexIH);

    split(complexIH, planes);
    outputImg = planes[0];
}
```

Refer to the tutorial for more information.